# How to add a tooltip to a datagrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

i have a wpf c# app.

I am using the datagrid control.

for one of these cells I want to show a mutli-line tool-tip.

this is my code:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static prop:Resources.Address}" Binding="{Binding Address}" >
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Line#1" />
            <TextBlock Text="Line#2" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

But when I run this no tool-tip is displayed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could set the Tooltip property of the DataGridCell using a CellStyle:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{x:Static prop:Resources.Address}" Binding="{Binding Address}" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ToolTip>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="Line#1" />
                            <TextBlock Text="Line#2" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: thanks. I could have sworn I tried that. I must have missed something out. many thanks :)